# Is it possible to use shell globs in /etc/logcheck/logcheck.logfiles?

Tags: logs, logcheck

I have a bunch of log files that correspond to remote hosts which vary by host name, split off using rsyslog. Can I use shell globs to refer to those log files instead of hard coding the file names in `/etc/logcheck/logcheck.logfiles`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is actually possible to use shell globs when setting the log files (tested with `logcheck 1.3.14`), even though it isn't mentioned in the documentation.

```
# these files will be checked by logcheck
# This has been tuned towards a default syslog install
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/*-auth.log
/var/log/*-syslog
```

In this case it would be looking for files where the host name would be prepended to the log file name under `/var/log`.